# Pulling in ID of model to save with form of other model

Tags: angular

Building a template form to save a PROJECT. When the page loads I'm using OnInit to pull in CLIENTS. I'm displaying an html select list of client names from my NodeJS API. Below the html select list, I'm starting a FORM with fields to eventually save a PROJECT.

I'm trying to include the CLIENT ID from the original select list of CLIENTS to add along with the form data so I can send up all data to my API and include a ref to the PROJECT ID in the CLIENT document for future merge API calls.

The problem is, the select list is outside the form tags so the value of the model is undefined when I save the form data.

What's the best way to manage this?

```
--pseudo code --

<select *ngFor="let client of clients">
<option>{{ client.name }}
</select>

<form>
......

<button type=submit></button>
</form>
```

Comment: What forms you are using ? . 
Try to add the select fields manually to the form when submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code through which you can get the clientID .

*.html file*

```
--pseudo code --

<select  (change)="selectChange($event)">
<option *ngFor="let client of clients" value="{{client.id}}"> {{ client.name }}
</select>

<form>
......

<button type=submit></button>
</form>
```

**.ts file**

```
 //Declare the global variable ,
    selectedOptionID;

    //create a function that handles the onChange event of select tag.

    selectCHange(event){
       console.log(event.target.value);
       this.selectedOptionID = event.target.value;
    }

  //now  when you submit your form , assign the value of **selectedOptionId** of the respected field of your form.
```

Through this , you will get the value of CLIENT-ID in the ts field after  submitting the form.

Hope you got the point .